# Get titleLabel during drag and drop

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, drag

An array of UIButton are generated programmatically. Is it possible to get the titleLabel of the UIButton triggering the drag? Or are there any ways to get info of the UIButton in the drag function?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for q in question{
       addButton(title:q)
    }
}

func addButton(title:String){
        var tbutton: UIButton = {

            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                                width: buttonWidth,
                                                height: buttonHeight))
            button.center = self.view.center
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button.layer.masksToBounds = true
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)             


            return button
        }()
        view.addSubview(tbutton)
        tbutton.addTarget(self,
                          action: #selector(drag(control:event:)),
                          for: UIControl.Event.touchDragInside)
        tbutton.addTarget(self,
                          action: #selector(drag(control:event:)),
                          for: [UIControl.Event.touchDragExit,
                                UIControl.Event.touchDragOutside]) 
        self.buttonArray.append(tbutton)

    }



    @objc func drag(control: UIControl, event: UIEvent) {
        //print(event)
        if let center = event.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
            control.center = center
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////  
        // Get titleLabel of the button here???????????
        /////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        button.center = CGPoint.init(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2)
        view.addSubview(button)

        let pangesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.panning(_:)))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(pangesture)

    }

    @objc func panning(_ panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let button = panGesture.view as! UIButton
        switch panGesture.state{
        case .changed:
            button.center = panGesture.location(in: view)
            panGesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
        default:
            break
        }

        // here you can get the button's properties too.
    }
}
```

Comment: if let center = event.allTouches?.first?.location(in: self.view) {
            control.center = center
 } How should I update this part in the drag function?

Comment: @Stephen I updated my answer.. this time we use pan gesture to do the dragging instead of the event in the button inside. Interesting question actually.. Because I was actually stuck when trying to unwrap UIButton to UIControl and its events.. But the solution using a pan gesture to drag button around is more elegant and can leave the functionality of button, which is click, for other implementation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Stephen just a side note. You can implement a logic for the .began in the gesture switch function, so that when you click your button will move to that position.. It will look more smooth.. But it is up to you to explore

Comment: if you are dragging multiple buttons.. rememebr to set the propery of the button, isSelector or other ways to identify the button from each other.. and use this property to drag the selected buttons together.